# All document in single font (I need math operator in Times New Roman)

Tags: math-mode, fonts, xetex, mathspec, times

The task arose to create a template in which the text and mathematical formulas are written in the Times New Roman font, since it is the standard in Russian universities. It turned out almost everything, except for some characters, please tell me how it can be corrected? Perhaps you already have a template where everything is written in a single font?

My code

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {longtable}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\usepackage{euscript}


\usepackage{icomma}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\newcommand*{\myfont}{Times New Roman}
\setallmainfonts[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.975]{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont(Digits,Greek,Latin){\myfont}
\setmathfont(Greek)[Lowercase=Regular]{\myfont}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{6pt}{6pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{6pt}{6pt}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top = 2cm, bottom = 2cm, left = 3cm, right = 2cm}

\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=black
}

\RequirePackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{defffis}{ --- }
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centerlast,labelsep=defffis,textfont=onehalfspacing}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedleft,labelsep=defffis,textfont=onehalfspacing,singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-6pt}


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\justifying
\sloppy
\tolerance=500
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\emergencystretch=3em
```

[image: Example]

Comment: does it really have to be exactly times new roman not a clone such as tex gyre termes, as far as I know there is no simple math setup for times new roman as it's not an opentype math font.  with tex gyre termes you can simply use `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`  with unicode-math package

Comment: And is this the only thing? It's just weird that everything else works. I found this phrase in the documentation for the mathspec package. That is, in unicode-math, characters can also be written in a single font along with the rest of the text. 

[Touch me](https://imgur.com/a/G8JIiVG)

Comment: nothing will be set up for math, with times new roman, obviously the main characters are there but without a math table the math typesetting has no infomation about any math specific features such as subscript positions  large delimiters, fraction positions etc, all the math-specific typographic features require a math font

Comment: Have you ever heard of the \mathfont package. I almost succeeded with it, but a bug appeared - the quotation mark appears incorrectly. Do you know how to fix it? [TOUCH ME PLEASE](https://imgur.com/a/XJhbzlp)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

Be careful: some Linux boxen ship with a version of Times New Roman from last century.  You can load TeX Gyre Termes instead if this causes a problem.

You still want to load most of the same packages, but not `amsfonts`, `amssymb` or `euscript`, all of which are superceded by `unicode-math`.  They shouldn’t do any harm, but they won’t work.  If you need something close to  Euler Script as `\mathscr`, you can add the line

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={scr,bfscr},
                                Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

(There is also an OpenType version of AMS Euler, including script and fraktur, if you want it.)

If you do not want to use `unicode-math`, alternatives include:

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{mathastext}
```

There might be a few incompatibilities with some Greek letters.

Or, in XeLaTeX:

```
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Times New Roman}
```

Comment: This is absolutely not what is required. In any case, not for the Russian contingent.

Comment: Have you watched how unicode-math works? Text in TNR font, formulas in TeX Gyre, symbols in standard (Latin Modern (?)) font. I am silent about the received restrictions in mathematics. You can't use mathematical symbols in the headers after that. It's just unusable!

Comment: @СергейКорягин It sounded to me like you currently were getting your symbols in Latin Modern and wanted them to be from (a clone of) Times. If you want it the other way around, you can load Latin Modern Math or New Computer Modern Math, then load your alphabets over it with `range=`.

Comment: @СергейКорягин However, it’s not clear to me what you are asking for.

Comment: @СергейКорягин If I understand you correctly, you also want to be able to load math symbols from 8-bit fonts together with `unicode-math`. This is almost always an XY-problem, but the way to do it is `\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathSymbol...}`.

Comment: I want the entire document to be in the Times New Roman and I sincerely do not understand why this cannot be done. I tried the unicode-math package, but it causes errors, if, for example, I want to insert mathematical symbols in the title of a chapter, there is a conflict with the hyperref package.

Comment: I am really pleased that you are trying to help me. In the examples you have suggested, half of the characters are written as needed, and half are not, and this makes me very sad

Comment: @СергейКорягин Could you describe what you want more clearly?

Comment: Sorry, but i can show it only in [pic](https://imgur.com/a/SjaPygV)

Comment: @СергейКорягин I’m having some difficulty understanding what you’re telling me is happening now, and what you want to happen instead.

Comment: I think I explained quite well that when using your example, \hbar is written at least not in italics, but at most it has a completely different font. About the unicode-math package: why can't I use a comma in formulas after connecting it? Error in the style: Missing { inserted. 0,1. Why can't I use mathematical symbols in the chapter title?

Comment: @СергейКорягин I’m sorry, but I’m genuinely having some trouble understanding you, because English doesn’t seem to be your native language and you aren’t using auxiliary verbs like “want to” or “should.” Could you please do me a favor and complete this sentence? “Currently, TeX is giving me _____. I want it to _____.”

Comment: @СергейКорягин You’re asking several other questions in your comment that sound like good questions for the site. It’s definitely possible to use commas and formulas in the chapter title in `unicode-math`, but I can’t tell you what your problem is without a MWE. I’ll take a wild guess that maybe `hyperref` is giving you some trouble when it tries to add formulas in a section title to the document outline. You might solve this with `\texorpdfstring`, and `unicode-math` makes this easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your answers and attempts to help me. I thought about my problem more deeply and came to an unexpected conclusion. Many of the characters I need simply do not exist in the Times New Roman font, which apparently people who come up with standards do not know. The problems that I described, I solved a little differently.

Comment: First, I accepted that I would have to use a separate mathematical font, similar to Times New Roman. Instead of a simple `hyperref`, I used `\usepackage[unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]`. Secondly, LaTeX has a habit of putting a space after the decimal point in the decimal fraction, because of this there was an error-a conflict with `unicode-math`. Later I will post a solution that satisfied me, but for now I want to thank @Davislor again for the help and for coming to terms with my English:)

Answer (score 0):

**[Solution path]**

First, I had to accept the fact that `Times New Roman` is not a mathematical font by default. Times New Roman simply does not contain some symbols, such as the reduced Planck constant or the partial differential. I decided to use `Latin Modern Math`.

Secondly, the structure of the code has been changed, and I am applying it here because I believe that I am not the only person who was looking for ways to solve the problem.

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}


\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{texdate}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage {tabularx}
\usepackage {longtable}
\usepackage {multirow}
\usepackage {multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{euscript}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}                 
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{icomma}


\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{6pt}{6pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{6pt}{6pt}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper, top = 2cm, bottom = 2cm, left = 3cm, right = 2cm}

\usepackage[unicode,psdextra]{hyperref}[2012/08/13]
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=black
}

\RequirePackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{defffis}{ --- }
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centerlast,labelsep=defffis,textfont=onehalfspacing}
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedleft,labelsep=defffis,textfont=onehalfspacing,singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup{belowskip=-6pt}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{microtype}
\justifying
\sloppy
\tolerance=500
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\emergencystretch=3em
```